# Calling a script function in a QUERY statement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-query-language

In the QUERY "select" clause it states that you can use a scalar function in place of 
a column name, for example "year(A)".

And in another part of the documentation it states that you can call a script 
function by coding "=function_name(...)" into the cell.

My question is: can you use a script function as a "scalar function" in a QUERY
statement?

If possible, it would greatly simplify code and might improve performance,
for some cases, for example "copying data from one sheet to another".

Here is my example

```
Assume "test" is a function that issues a "return" statement that modifies
its input parameter.
```

I have tried the code

```
=test(A1)
```

in a cell and it works.

But when I try this QUERY

```
=QUERY(A1:A10, "select test(A)" )
```

it fails. My guess it does not like the "test(A)" value. 
Is there some way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: can you use a script function as a "scalar function"
>   in a QUERY statement?

No you can't, unfortunately.

Reading between the lines, I think what you would need to do is to modify your script such that it accepts an array as an argument, do what it needs to do over that array, and return a result array.  Then you would be able to invoke something like:

```
=test(A1:A10)
```

or you could include that as your *first* argument in a QUERY statement:

```
=QUERY(test(A1:A10);"select Col1 where Col1 contains 'x'")
```

Comment: Adani, thank you for your suggestion. I like using the function as a source for the query. It is a good solution.